# Text file to sorted binary File, C Language

Tags: c, sorting, text-files, structure, binaryfiles

we were asked to alphabetically sort the contents(in this case, the R.name) of a text file and write it into a binary file without saving it to an array. What I've done so far is to just write all the contents of a text file into the binary file, but I don't know how to properly sort it in a binary file. We were told that we CAN use insertion sort but I don't have any idea on how to sort binary files not know the number of structures inside.

textFile[], and binFile[] are the names of the text file and binary file respectively

```
void textToBinary(char textFile[], char binFile[])
{
FILE * fp;
FILE * fp2;
char ch;
String20 dump;
int i;
structRecipe R;
long int npos;

if( (fp = fopen (textFile, "r")) != NULL)
{   
if((fp2 = fopen (binFile, "wb"))!= NULL)
{

while( fgets(R.name, 21, fp) != NULL)
{
R.name[strlen(R.name) -1] = '\0';
fscanf(fp, "%d%c%s%c", &R.nServings, &ch, R.classifications, &ch);
fscanf(fp, "%s%c%d%c", dump, &ch, &R.nIng, &ch);    

for(i=0; i<R.nIng; i++)
{
fscanf(fp, "%f%c%s%c", &R.Ingredients[i].quantity, &ch, 
R.Ingredients[i].unit, &ch);
fgets(R.Ingredients[i].item, 21, fp);
R.Ingredients[i].item[strlen(R.Ingredients[i].item) - 1] = '\0';
}

fscanf(fp, "%s%c%d%c", dump, &ch, &R.nSteps, &ch);

for(i=0; i< R.nSteps; i++)
{
fgets(R.steps[i], 71, fp);
}

fscanf(fp, "%c", &ch);
fseek(fp2, 0, SEEK_END);
fwrite(&R, sizeof(structRecipe), 1, fp2);

}
fclose(fp2);
}
fclose(fp);
}
else printf("Error opening file for reading \n");
}
`
```

can I have even just ideas on how to sort it without saving the contents of the binary file into an array? (using c language)

Comment: Please edit your code and use intend to be more readable.

Comment: I tried doing that at first but the website won't let me upload it with the 'proper' indention

Answer (score 0):

An insertion sort might look like this:

```
structRecipe R, tR, *pR[2];
int x, written=0;

pR[0]=&R;
pR[1]=&tR;

            ... fill R....
            fscanf(fp, "%c", &ch);

            fseek(fp2, 0, SEEK_SET);
            x=0;
            for(j=0; j<written; j++) {
                fread(&tR, sizeof(structRecipe), 1, fp2);
                if(strcmp(R.name, tR.name)<0) {
                    fwrite(&R, sizeof(structRecipe), 1, fp2);
                    x=!x;
                    break;
                }
            }
            for(; j<written; j++) {
                fread(pR[!x], sizeof(structRecipe), 1, fp2);
                fseek(fp2, -sizeof(structRecipe), SEEK_CUR);
                fwrite(pR[x], sizeof(structRecipe), 1, fp2);
                x=!x;
            }
            fwrite(pR[x], sizeof(structRecipe), 1, fp2);
            written++;

        }
        fclose(fp2);
```

Sorry, it's untested, only an idea.

Comment: will try to get something out of this, Thank you!!